# Spideroak Why is show file history greyed out?

Tags: cloud-storage

When I right click on a file that is being backed up in SpiderOak all of the options are greyed out including the "Show File History" choice.

Answer (score 0):

I after some research found that I caused the problem by **navigating to the file using a symlink** (junction).

When I navigated to the file (in Explorer) using the "original path" (not via a junction), the "Show File History" choice appeared and I could select it and view the history.

The lesson learned is: When using SpiderOak to view history use the path that is being "backed up".